# Getting latest details of an employee

Tags: oracle11g

I have 2 tables personal_details
[personal_details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCD6C.jpg)
and post_details
[post_details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzRlY.jpg)

first table has all personal details of the employee and the second one has the latest transfer details

i want to join the two tables and get only latest transfer details based on the max(from_date) column

the query which tried gives all the transfer details

```
select pe.emp_id,pe.full_name,po.place,po.from_date from personal_details pe,post_details po
where pe.emp_id=po.emp_id
```

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT emp_id, full_name, place, from_date
FROM
(
    SELECT pe.emp_id, pe.full_name, po.place, po.from_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pe.emp_id ORDER BY po.from_date DESC) rn
    FROM personal_details pe
    INNER JOIN post_details po
        ON pe.emp_id = po.emp_id
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: can u give me mysql equivalent of the above query

Comment: @McNeilRodrigues You should open a new question and ask there.  You have already tagged this question for Oracle.